# Small capital in chapter title

Tags: fonts, bold, small-caps

I've defined the following command

```
\newcommand{\CI}{\textsc{Ci}~}
```

which produces a C with a small uppercase *i*.
The only problem I have is that when I use this command in the `\chapter` or `\section` environment the *i* is lower case.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The standard Computer Modern fonts don't have boldface small caps. If you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` you should get what you want.